# Difficult conjugation

Tags: grammar

I would appreciate help in understanding the following conjugation.
It is difficult to comprehend the English translation for this.

```
こんなことになっちゃんんじゃないの
```

Comment: Are there really two んs in a row?

Comment: what's the context?

Comment: Maybe こんなことになっちゃ**う**んじゃないの?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the んん is a dialect form or mistranscription of うん:

- こんな: this kind of
- こと: abstract thing → fact, happenstance, situation, etc.
- に: `[particle]`, here indicating the result of the following verb:
- なっちゃう → contraction of なって + しまう: to become, in an unfortunate way
- ん → contraction of の: `[particle]`, used here to nominalize the preceding phrase
- じゃ → contraction of で + は: `[particle]`
- ない: not
- の: `[particle]`, used here as a sentence-ending mood indicator: soft emphasis

In general, the cluster のではない → んじゃない expresses that the speaker thinks the part before this shouldn't happen, or shouldn't be done.

In this specific case, and without more context, the whole thing comes across to me as, *"It shouldn't turn out like this."*

Comment: `shouldn't happen, or shouldn't be done.`-> ?「（~だから）こんなことになっちゃうんじゃないの！」(=こんなことになるんじゃないか！/ こんな結果になってしまうんじゃないか！)　っていう非難の言葉じゃないんですかね・・(または「こんなふうになるんじゃないでしょうか？」っていう疑問文)